# UserControl with a ContextMenu property

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, contextmenu

How can I add in Silverlight a ContextMenu property to a UserControl (and how can I use it), if I want to add that ContextMenu just to one child-control in the UserControl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), then you can use the `ContextMenuService`.

You can add a `ContextMenu` to `UserControl` like this:-

```
 <UserControl ... blah blah...>
     <ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="First Item" Click="FirstItem_Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="Second Item" Click="SecondItem_Click" />
     </ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
     <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"> </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

You simple have the click event handlers in your code behind on the UserControl to respond to menu item selection.

If are using MVVM then `MenuItem` also has a `Command` property the you can bind to.

You can add this `ContextMenuService.ContextMenu` attached property to any framework element inside the UserControl if you want to provide specific menus for specific areas of the UI.

Comment: I want something like this: `myUserControl.ContextMenuProperty = new ContextMenu(); /* from the SL Toolkit */ ...`  and for example there is a GridView in the UserControl. I want to add that new ContextMenu just to the GridView, not to the whole UserControl.

Comment: @Perec:  I don't what `GridView` but I understand you correctly you want to build the Context menu on it using code not xaml, is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly! I want to create a ContextMenu, yes. Not in the UserControl, but in the MainView, and add it to my UserControl through a property. And then bind this property to a real control on the UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be achieved using SL4PopupMenu available as a Nuget package or downloadable here:

http://sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com

Then all you have to do is add the following property to your UserControl:

```
PopupMenu _menu;

PopupMenu Menu
{
    get
    {
        return _menu;
    }
    set
    {
        _menu = value;
        _menu.AddTrigger(TriggerTypes.RightClick, ChildControl);
    }
}
```

However there's yet another way to achieve this through selectors which the menu provides and which work much like those in jQuery. So depending on your requirements you might want to consider this path as well.